# WPF Image Control Source with Redirects

Tags: wpf

The XAML below works if Source points to an actual image.

```
<Image Source="http://somewhere.com/somewhere.png" />
```

But if the Source is a redirect from a url shortner service the image fails to load.

Is there a simple way to handle this or am I going to have to go down the rabbit hole and handle the redirects myself?

Comment: why do you have to a URL shortening? Cant you provide the actual full fledged URL to the Image Source?

Comment: The url comes from an external source.

Answer (score 2):

As the [`AllowAutoRedirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect.aspx) flag is set to `true` for WebClient instances (see Remarks [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.WebClient.aspx)), the following may work, and may perhaps be the easiest way to handle redirections. Note however that I didn't test it, as I had no redirected image URL at hand.

```
var url = ...
var buffer = (new WebClient()).DownloadData(url);
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
{
    bitmap.BeginInit();
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
    bitmap.EndInit();
}

image.Source = bitmap;
```

If it works, you may put this code in a binding converter.

---

Having said all this, I'd expect WPF's built in type converter (from URL string to ImageSource) to also use either HttpWebRequest or WebClient. For both the default behavior is to allow redirections. So maybe the redirection in your case fails for some other reason.

Comment: Could be that the redirect fails for some other reason. However, if I take the received url passed to the image source and paste it in the browser, it finds the image. I'll investigate further. Thanks.

Comment: Wasnt aware of WebCLient Celmens. Pretty neat.