# Image appears on my system but not on live system XAML - VB from remote location

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I've got a really strange issue when trying to add an image from a remote location using VB and XAML.

On my development machine it appears fine and is functioning correctly, however when I build this onto the live system the image does not appear.

XAML -

```
  <Grid Name="advert" Width="374" Canvas.Left="342" Canvas.Top="306" Panel.ZIndex="-100000">
        <Image Height="738" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-369,-333,-591,-405" Name="homeAdvert" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1334"/>
    </Grid>
```

VB

```
  homeAdvert.Source = New System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(New Uri(complete, UriKind.Absolute))
```

Complete is a variable that has been set to construct the URL, which seems to be correct as I can browse to it on the web browser of the live system. It also appears on my development system.

Comment: Can you post your complete image path ? In your case it must be a full path.

Comment: Hi - The complete image path is correct it is just not rendering it for some reason within the live code.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17262343/1136211

Comment: Any idea how I would implement this with VB? I'm unsure of what syntax i'd need to change.